# Check for spaces from input stdin in C not working

Tags: c, scanf

Hy guys,

I just started to learn C and I'm having a problem, with my code.
I'm trying to make a simple program which will take the input (name, password) and append it in a file.

```
int main()
{
    printf("1. Register\n");
    printf("2. Login\n");
    printf("Please enter your choice: ");

    int choice;

    FILE *file = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    if (file == NULL)
        printf("File cannot be oppened");

    char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char[64]));
    if (name == NULL)
        printf("name malloc failed");

    char *password = (char *)malloc(64 * sizeof(char));
    if (password == NULL)
        printf("password malloc failed");

    char *userInput = (char *)malloc(1024 * sizeof *userInput);
    if (userInput == NULL)
        printf("userInput malloc failed");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter username: ");
        fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]s\n", name);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", name);

        printf("Enter password: ");

        //check if there's any spaces 
        fscanf(stdin, "%[^\n]s\n", password);
        fprintf(file, "%s\n", password);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I want to check if password or name contains any space.
The compilation won't give me any error, but it will just print "enter username" and "enter password" and then will exit the program, if I don't use this check the program works accordingly.

the output when I try the check:

1. Register
2. Login

Please enter your choice: 1

Enter username: Enter password:

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the common error of adding an `s` after the `%[...]` format specifier. Don't add that. (Looking for a duplicate...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```c
char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char[64]));
```

You shouldn't malloc the sizeof an array you should rather use

```c
char *name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 64);
```

Also when you check that the malloc or file is `NULL`, if it fails you should return to stop the program.

Also as @user3121023 said you should change `"%[^\n]s\n"` to `" %[^\n]"` with the added space at the start.

Comment: Thank you  @user3121023, that works , how can I accept your answer as answered?

Comment: You cannot accept comments, but you can accept answers with the greyed out checkmark beneath the voting buttons.

Comment: `" %[^\n]"` without a _width_ is bad.    Better as `" %63[^\n]"`

Comment: Better to allocate to the reference object and not type. `name = malloc(sizeof name[0] * 64);`.  Cast not needed.